# How to edit and delete from json after displayed to a page

Tags: javascript, json, splice

Hello, I am extremely new to javascript and json and I am trying to edit and remove my JSON object from after it is displayed to the page.

Here is my html

```
enter code here
 <body>
    <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="main-heading">
        <div class="container">
        <!--  <h1 class="display-3">Fluid jumbotron</h1> -->
            <header><img src="pawneelogo.png" id="pawnee-logo" class="img-
                 fluid" alt="pawnee-logo"></header>
            <p class="lead">Add a new family member today!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
  <!--Animals-->
  <h1 class="display-3" id="animals">Adoptable Animals</h1>
  <hr>
  <div id="buttons-top">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-
  target="#add-animal">Add</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <!--Add New Modal--->
        <div class="modal fade" id="add-animal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="add form" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addAnimalLabel">Add an 
Animal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
aria-label="Close">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <form id="add-animal" method='#'>
                       <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputSpecies">Species:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="species">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputAge">Age:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="age">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputGender">Gender:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="gender">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="inputSize">Size:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="selectSize">
                                <option>Small</option>
                                <option>Medium</option>
                                <option>Large</option>
                                </select>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="inputChildFriendly">Child Friendly:
</label>
                            <select class="form-control" 
id="selectChildFriendly">
                                <option>true</option>
                                <option>false</option>
                                 </select>
                       </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="inputAdoptable">Adoptable:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" 
id="selectAdoptable">
                                <option>true</option>
                                <option>false</option>
                                 </select>
                       </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="physical-description">Physical 
Description:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="physical-
description" rows="4"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="history">History:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="history" 
rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputDateOfIntake">Date of Intake:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
id="dateOfIntake">
                        <label for="inputDateOfAdotion">Date of Adoption:
</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" 
id="dateOfAdoption"><br>
                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-
primary">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 <!---end add modal-->  

  <!---Edit Modal -->


  <!---Cards --->
  <div class="container" id="animal-listings">
      <div class="row">

        </div>

  </div>



  <!---End Cards--->


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pawneescript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$('document').ready(function(){

var adoptableAnimals = {

"animals" : [   

 {
 "Name": "Bubbles",
 "Species": "Dog",
 "Age": "Adult",
 "Gender": "Female",
  "Size": "Small",
 "Child Friendly": true,
 "Adoptable": true,
 "Physical Description": "Chihuahua & Dachsund Mix. 25 pound Chiweenie! She 
  gets along well with other dogs.",
   "History": "Found at West 25th and Lorain.",
  "Date of Intake": "10/20/2016 15:00",
   "Date of Adoption": "",
     "Identification": 1
 },
 {
"Name": "Lionel",
"Species": "Dog",
"Age": "Young",
"Gender": "Male",
"Size": "Large",
"Child Friendly": true,
 "Adoptable": true,
 "Physical Description": "Rebone Coonhound & Rhodesian Ridgeback Mix. Lionel 
is a 7.5 month old (as of 9/20), 56 pound Redbone Coonhound mix. He is truly 
a lover. Lionel wants to be with everyone at all times and loves affection. 
He fits in well with any gang! He loves dogs of all ages, both small and 
large.He knows the commands: sit, come, and down. He?s a smart little, or 
should we say big, guy! \n\nHe loves the outdoors and his walks. He 
possesses the right amount of playfulness and energy! He enjoys playing with 
his toys, other dogs, and his humans. Being pet is one of his favorite 
things. Lionel is VERY affectionate. He will sit with you on the couch or 
lounge around with you on your day off. \n\nLionel walks well on a leash and 
does not bark often. This gentleman is also house trained! He?s a well-
rounded, large puppy that is looking for his forever cuddler! ",
"History": "Owner surrendor, moving to apartment that does not allow dogs.",
"Date of Intake": "9/16/2016 11:30",
"Date of Adoption": "",
    "Identification": 2
 },
  {
   "Name": "Ruby",
   "Species": "Dog",
   "Age": "Young",
   "Gender": "Female",
   "Size": "Large",
  "Child Friendly": false,
  "Adoptable": true,
   "Physical Description": "Ruby appears to be a striking mix of Doberman 
   Pinscher and German Shepherd....",
"History": "Owner surrendor, moving to apartment that does not allow dogs.",
"Date of Intake": "11/16/2016 9:15",
"Date of Adoption": "",
    "Identification": 3
  },
 {
 "Name": "Neil",
  "Species": "Cat",
  "Age": "Young",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Size": "Medium",
  "Child Friendly": true,
  "Adoptable": true,
 "Physical Description": "Neil is a loving kitten looking a lot of rest, 
  antibiotics, and affection!... \n",
 "History": "Found in Brooklyn, Ohio",
 "Date of Intake": "11/2/2016 9:30",
  "Date of Adoption": "",
   "Identification": 4
  },
  {
   "Name": "Jenna",
   "Species": "Cat",
   "Age": "Adult",
   "Gender": "Female",
   "Size": "Medium",
   "Child Friendly": true,
   "Adoptable": true,
  "Physical Description": "Hi, I'm Jenna. ....",
   "History": "Found in Cleveland, Ohio",
   "Date of Intake": "11/10/2016 14:00",
   "Date of Adoption": "",
   "Identification": 5
 },
 {
   "Name": "Ginga Ninja",
   "Species": "Cat",
    "Age": "Young",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Size": "Medium",
   "Child Friendly": true,
   "Adoptable": true,
  "Physical Description": "Born about November, 2015, Ginga Ninja....",
   "History": "Found near JACK casino.",
   "Date of Intake": "10/18/2016 16:05",
   "Date of Adoption": "",
   "Identification":6
  },
   {
 "Name": "Leo",
 "Species": "Cat",
 "Age": "Adult",
 "Gender": "Male",
 "Size": "Medium",
  "Child Friendly": true,
  "Adoptable": true,
  "Physical Description": "Leo is not ....",
   "History": "Transfer from City Shelter",
  "Date of Intake": "11/19/2016 12:23",
  "Date of Adoption": "",
   "Identification": 7
 },
 {
 "Name": "Volcano",
 "Species": "Other",
 "Age": "Young",
 "Gender": "Male",
 "Size": "Medium",
 "Child Friendly": true,
  "Adoptable": true,
  "Physical Description": "Volcano is a young ....",
   "History": "Owner surrendor.",
   "Date of Intake": "11/18/2016 1:18pm",
   "Date of Adoption": "",
     "Identification":8
 },
 {
 "Name": "Li'l Britches",
 "Species": "Other",
  "Age": "Adult",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "Size": "Medium",
  "Child Friendly": true,
   "Adoptable": true,
   "Physical Description": "Please meet Li'l Britches!....",
   "History": "Owner surrendor.",
   "Date of Intake": "11/15/2016 15:40",
   "Date of Adoption": "",
   "Identification": 9
 }
 ]
  }



/*Loop Through Animals*/

for (var i = 0; i < adoptableAnimals.animals.length; i++){
  console.log(adoptableAnimals);

   $('.row').append("<div class='card' style='width: 30rem; margin-
right:1em; margin-bottom: 1em;'><div class='card-body'><h4>"+ 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Name + "</h4><h5>" + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Species + "</h5><h6>" + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Age + "</h6><h6>" + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Gender + "</h6><h6>" + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Size + "</h6><p>Child Friendly: " + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Child Friendly"] + "</p><p>Adoptable: " + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Adoptable + "</p><p>" + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Physical Description"] + "</p><p>History: " + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i].History + "</p><p>Date of Intake: " + 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Date of Intake"]+ "</p><p>Date of Adoption: "+ 
adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Date of Adoption"]+ "</p><button type'button' 
class='btn edit-btn btn-primary'>Edit</button><button type'button' 
class='btn remove-btn btn-primary'>Remove</button></div></div>" ); 


/*Add new animal to JSON*/


  $("#submit").click(function(){

  var name = $("#name").val();
  var species = $("#species").val();
  var age = $("#age").val();
  var gender = $("#gender").val();
  var size = $("#selectSize").val();
  var childFriendly = $("#selectChildFriendly").val();
   var adoptable = $("#selectAdoptable").val();
   var physicalDescription = $("#physical-description").val();
  var history = $("#history").val();
  var dateOfIntake = $("#dateOfIntake").val();
  var dateOfAdoption = $("#dateOfAdoption").val();

  var newAnimal = {
    Name: name,
    Species: species,
    Age: age,
    Gender: gender,
    Size: size,
    "Child Friendly": childFriendly,
    Adoptable: adoptable,
    "Physical Description": physicalDescription,
    History: history,
    "Date of Intake": dateOfIntake,
    "Date of Adoption": dateOfAdoption,
   Identification: adoptableAnimals.animals.length + 1
  }


  console.log(newAnimal); 
  adoptableAnimals.animals.push(newAnimal);

console.log(adoptableAnimals);

  if (adoptableAnimals.animals.length > 15){
      alert("Sorry. Our shelter is currently full. We can no longer accept 
    incoming animals");
  }
  else{ $('.row').append("<div class='card' style='width: 30rem; margin-
 right:1em; margin-bottom: 1em;'><div class='card-body'><h4>"+ 
 newAnimal.Name + "</h4><h5>" + newAnimal.Species + "</h5><h6>" + 
 newAnimal.Age + "</h6><h6>" + newAnimal.Gender + "</h6><h6>" + 
 newAnimal.Size + "</h6><p>Child Friendly: " + newAnimal["Child Friendly"] + 
 "</p><p>Adoptable: " + newAnimal.Adoptable + "</p><p>" + 
 newAnimal["Physical Description"] + "</p><p>History: " + newAnimal.History 
 + "</p><p>Date of Intake: " + newAnimal["Date of Intake"]+ "</p><p>Date of 
 Adoption: "+ newAnimal["Date of Adoption"]+ "</p><button type'button' 
 class='btn edit-btn btn-primary'>Edit</button><button type'button' 
 class='btn remove-btn btn-primary'>Remove</button></div></div>"); 


  };
 $("#add-animal").modal("hide");

 $('#add-animal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $(this).find("input,textarea,select").val('').end()



  });


  });

  });
```

I am not sure how to proceed to remove an item from the json array. I've tried using splice, but I can't get it to work.

I also would like to be able to edit a value in the json and am not sure how to proceed with that either.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. I am still trying to understand all of this. Thanks.

Comment: please make the question shorter and easier to read by omitting the unnecessary HTML.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure which parts you would need to see and what you wouldn't. I want to  be able to remove an  item from the array and to edit

Answer (score 0):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) requires an index to the element you want to remove. Create a function to find the index by some property and then call splice with the found index. The code below searches animals by name.

```
function getAnimalIndex(animalName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < adoptableAnimals.animals.length; i++) {
        if (adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Name === animalName);
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function removeAnimal(animalName) {
    var index = getAnimalIndex(animalName);
    if (index >= 0) {
        adoptableAnimals.animals.splice(index, 1);
        renderAnimals();
    }
}

function renderAnimals() {
    $('.row').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < adoptableAnimals.animals.length; i++) {
        $('.row').append("<div class='card' style='width: 30rem; margin-right: 1e m; margin - bottom: 1e m;'><div class='card - body '><h4>"+ 
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Name + "</h4><h5>" +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Species + "</h5><h6>" +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Age + "</h6><h6>" +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Gender + "</h6><h6>" +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Size + "</h6><p>Child Friendly: " +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Child Friendly"] + "</p><p>Adoptable: " +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].Adoptable + "</p><p>" +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Physical Description"] + "</p><p>History: " +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i].History + "</p><p>Date of Intake: " +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Date of Intake"] + "</p><p>Date of Adoption: " +
            adoptableAnimals.animals[i]["Date of Adoption"] + "</p><button type'button' class = 'btn edit-btn btn-primary' > Edit < /button><button type'button' class = 'btn remove-btn btn-primary' > Remove < /button></div > < /div>" );
    }
    initRemoveListeners();
}
```

Comment: Ok so I have put my loop into a function...and when I click the remove button, it removes the object from my array, but how can I get it to show a new array without the one I just removed.

       $(".remove-btn").click(function(){
        adoptableAnimals.animals.splice(0, 1);
         console.log(adoptableAnimals);
         loopAnimals();
               
         
     });

Comment: extract your render logic into a function and call it after the removal. Also clear the existing content

Comment: Like I said I'm new to this and I truly appreciate your help, but...whats the render logic? Does that mean putting the splice into a function and then call the function after the removal?

Comment: by render logic i mean the part where you create your rows in the table

Comment: How can I edit the values? Should I use replaceWith?

Comment: Yes sorry. Like if I wanted to change adoptable to not adoptable, or change the age

Comment: Use the `getAnimalIndex` to find the index and then update the array object. `adoptableAnimals.animals[index].foo = 'bar'`

Comment: You have really been so helpful! Thank you so much! I just have one last question. If I want to filter through or sort the array, should I use the filter method?

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your quick responses and help. I hope you have a wonderful week!

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

slice is working fine

//these will return top 2 rows where 0 is startindex and 2 is the endIndex
`adoptableAnimals.animals = adoptableAnimals.animals.slice(0,2)`

`console.log(adoptableAnimals.animals)`

if you want to edit
use

`adoptableAnimals.animals[0].Name = "first array name will change a index position zero"`

to know exactly what happening you could use

`console.log(adoptableAnimals.animals)` then

`f12 in chrome` and in console tab you can check the values

Comment: Ok so I've added this code to remove on the click, but I can only do it once. How can I remove another animal after that?

       $(".remove-btn").click(function(){
        adoptableAnimals.animals.splice(0, 1);
         console.log(adoptableAnimals);
         $('.row').empty();         
         loopAnimals();
             
     });

Comment: add onClick function on remove-btn and pass i to that function `<button type'button' class='btn edit-btn btn-primary'>Edit</button><button type'button' class='btn remove-btn btn-primary' onclick='test("+i+")'>` 

function test(i) {
   //use splice function here
  adoptableAnimals.animals.splice(i, 1); 
}